# OpenXML ошибается в кол-ве колонок таблицы или кривая таблица?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

В общем, читаю свойства таблицы и на основании:

```
<w:tblGrid xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:gridCol w:w="1395"/>
    <w:gridCol w:w="15"/>
    <w:gridCol w:w="8161"/>
</w:tblGrid>
```

Я делаю вывод, что в таблице 3 ячейки.

Смотрю в саму таблицу, а там на протяжении всей таблицы идут 2 колонки.

У одной из ячеей стоит `<w:gridSpan w:val="2" />`.

Получается, что было сделано слияние ячеек? Если слияние делается по всей таблице, то разве `<w:gridSpan w:val="2" />` должен писаться?

Посмотрел таблицу со спец. символами и не увидел ничего криминального:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли избавиться от этой фантомной ячейки?

Comment: Просто он так считает. Т.е. width(А)=>1395  width(B+gridSpan=2) => 15+8161 Ведь если вы захотите "разеденить" ячейки - нужно знать ширину столбца.

Comment: @nick_n_a, как нибудь можно пофиксить?

Comment: Пофиксить что? это такое "представление" данных. Если стоит colSpan = 2 то ширину ячейки что б посчитать - нужно суммировать w. Фантомные столбцы оно не пишет (не фиксирует, но считает), а фантомные строки - пишет.

Comment: Возможно... вам нужно "обойти" таблицу по-строкам, и просканировать её на наличие gridSpan по всему столбцу - только тогда будет понятно что столбец "ушёл", но логически он то есть (если пользователь удалит обьединение - вернётся столбец). Я помню свой ответ, может его нужно ещё дописать. Возможно таки надо преобразовать всё в структуру (text, x, y, colspan, rowspan) и сделать из неё выборку. Тогда результат будет более понятен.

Comment: Вы писали "дублировать данные в обьеденённых" ячейках. Из этого следует что у вас три столбца? Ведь так? Просто первая ячейка = один слолбец таблицы, а вторая ячейка (colSpan=2) - два столбца таблицы.

Comment: @nick_n_a, визуально ворд показывает на протяжении всей таблицы 2 ячейки в шапке и в последующих колонках.

Comment: это понятно, нужно или "включить разметку", или войти в режим "конструктор таблицы" или проверить есть ли кнопка "разеденить ячейки" (или как она называется). Тогда будет видно ещё один столбец. (народ часто вбивает таблицу как-попало и не всегда делает её правильно)

Comment: @nick_n_a А как такое могло получится? Получается, что кто-то смержил какие-то ячейки между собой в ворде?

Comment: Да.Например, нарисовал таблицу с лишним столбцом, потом нажал "резинку" и удалил линию резинкой (считается мержем) вместо ф-ции удалить столбцы.

Comment: @nick_n_a печально. Только итеративно можно решить эту проблему и удалить фантомов или есть какой-нибудь метод "сделать все хорошо"?

Comment: Как я говорил, привести всё в таблицу вида (text,x,y,colspan,rowspan) и проанализировав её сделать "упрощение"

Comment: @nick_n_a, а однозначно определить является ли таблица "больной" без глубокого анализа можно?

Comment: @nick_n_a, решение нашел. Если в Word сделать AutoFit колонок во весь экран, то этот левое объединение колонок пропадает. Можно ли подобное проделать средствами OpenXML?

Comment: Я не работал с  OpenXML. Я с чистым xml работал.